# How to replace GLUT's functions with own code on windows?

Tags: windows, opengl

I'm reading an OpenGL book (OpenGL superbible 5th edition) and it uses GLUT so that it can centre in OpenGL without losing time with platform-specific programming. But the problem is that it has it's own program loop, and I wanted to know if there is any tutorial or something that teaches me how to setup a OpenGL window ready for drawing without OpenGL, on windows.
For example, using glut, i can set up everything with this code:

```
gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
```

And i want to do what that lines of code do, manually (well, not exactly like this, I don't want to create a similar system to glut where you set callback functions that are called when something changes)

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, but [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net) is a more or less straight replacement of GLUT, but does allow you control over the main loop, should you wish to do so.

Comment: I'd recommend GLFW instead. In this framework you're responsible for implementing the event loop which is the sane thing to do.

Comment: That code actually uses freeglut, but I've read it is like the GLUT version of MacOSX, but on windows. Anyways, I want to do it without it. Thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: Thanks datenwolf, I'll try with that. But I'd prefer If someone can point me to a tutorial that teaches to do what this libraries do

Comment: @XaitormanX: "But I'd prefer If someone can point me to a tutorial that teaches to do what this libraries do" Honestly, if you're still in the "I need a tutorial" phase of learning something, then you aren't ready to do this. Initializing and managing an OpenGL window requires direct interface with not only low-level Win32/X-Windows stuff, but also WGL/GLX stuff. This is not trivial code, and it's generally not "tutorial" material. It's not the same across platforms, and knowing how to do it tells you nothing about how to use OpenGL itself.

Comment: I think I can say that I'm not in that phase anymore, at least not much.I wasn't exactly asking for a complete tutorial, but something to start reading about it. I supposed it is not an easy thing and that is different in each platform, but i wanted to try at least. But if no one knows some good article or something, I'll just keep reading and searching. Thank you for your help